# Show that a polynomial p can't have both roots 1 and i

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I have to show that a polynomial $p\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ where $p\neq0$, can't have both roots, $1$ and $i$, where $i^2=-1$. The polynomial has degree 2 or less.

$p(\alpha)=c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2$

I know that, when we want to find the roots of a function, we have to solve the function for $x$ so that $f(x)=0$

I don't know how to solve this kind of question, when $p$ cant be equal to $0$ and I have to show that the polynomial $p\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ can't have both roots 1 and $i$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: having roots means you can factorize $p(x)=c(x-1)(x-i)$, is this still a real polynomial ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If a polynomial with real coefficients has root $i$, then it has root $-i$ as well

Comment: @TarekBadr the statement is false. For instance $p(x) = (x-1)(x^2+1)$ has roots $1$,$i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @PierreCarre I believe OP is only considering polynomials of degree 2 or less

Comment: @PierreCarre:  but that doesn't have the form $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2$

Comment: @NicholasRoberts The OP mentions $\mathbb{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$... Maybe he can clarify.

Comment: I have to show it for a polynomial of degree 2 or less

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The OP mentions $\mathbb{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$... Polynomials of degree less or equal than 3. maybe he can clarify.

Comment: If that's the case, then @J.W.Tanner 's comment will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

If we have a polynomial with real coefficients, with $z$ as a root, one can check that $\overline{z}$ must also be a root of the polynomial. Thus, if $i$ is a root of a polynomial $p$, then so is $-i$. If we also require that $1$ be a root of $p$, then $p$ has at least $3$ roots. But how many roots can $p$ have, given that it's of degree at most $2$?

Comment: The polynomial can't have more than 2 roots, because we are working with a polynomial with degree 2 or less, right?

Comment: Complex roots are pairwise conjugate only  if the polynomial has real coefficients.

Comment: @Tarek Bdr Yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good theorem I suggest you to know:

> Let $P(x)$ a polynomial of degree $n$ (with real coefficents) of the form $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots a_1x+x_0$ has:
>
> A)An even number of real solutions (counted with their multiplicity) if $n$ is even;
>
> B)An odd number of real solutions (counted with their multiplicity) if $n$ is odd.

This is a powerful theorem and sowe understood that $P(\alpha)$ can't have zeros $i$ and $1$ because the degree of $P$ is $2$, we have $0$ or $2$ real solutions (counted with their multiplicity).

Answer (score 0):

If
$p(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2
$
then
$p(1) = c_0+c_1+c_2
$
and
$p(i) = c_0+ic_1-c_2
$.

If
$p(1) = p(i) = 0$
then,
adding these,
$0
=2c_0+(1+i)c_1
=2c_0+c_1+ic_1
$.
Since all the $c_j$
are real,
this implies that
$c_1 = 0$
and
$2c_0+c_1 = 0$
so $c_0 = 0$.
Since
$c_0+c_1+c_2 0$,
$c_2 = 0$
so the polynomial
is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the fuss... Just write $p(x)=(x-1)(x-i)$ and expand it to get $p(x)=x^2-(1+i)x+i$, which clearly does not belong to $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$. Or is it?

Comment: but what do i have to do with $p(x)=x^2-(1+i)x+i$

Comment: That polynomial does not have real coefficients and hence is not an element of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. Contradiction.

Comment: oooooh, i see that.

Comment: To be rigourous, there should be a constant in front office the product. $p(x)=c(x-1)(x-i)$ and then argue that no value of $c$ will make both $c$ and $ci$ real numbers.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Great comment, thanks. That's it: don't forget the constant and proceed with the proof by contradiction.

Comment: You should edit your post to include this modification.